# How to find list of files in "StreamingAssets" folder in Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some files in my StreamingAssets folder and I am able to load them on Android as mentioned in the Unity documentation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

But here I need to know the filename in advance.

Now I want to get list of all the files I have added in this directory. Following code does not work on Android. It gives directory not found exception.

```
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
    FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
```

So I want to know how do I get list of files in my StreamingAssets folder on Android. I need the file name so I can access the filename.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Use Better Streaming Assets, a free and open source plug in that parses APK/OBB archive to get the list of streaming assets. It also lets you read them without WWW.

Asset Store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/103788

Github: https://github.com/gwiazdorrr/BetterStreamingAssets

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this is to write the list of files in a .txt file before building the application and load the .txt file to access the file paths later in-game.

Add the `BuildProcessor.cs` script anywhere in your project, it will be executed each time you build the application.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using UnityEngine;

class BuildProcessor : IPreprocessBuildWithReport
{
    public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("OnPreprocessBuild");

        SaveStreamingAssetPaths();
    }

    private void SaveStreamingAssetPaths(string directory = "", string file_name = "StreamingAssetPaths")
    {
        List<string> paths = StreamingAssetsExtension.GetPathsRecursively(directory); // Gets list of files from StreamingAssets/directory

        // You could also save paths of files in Resources
        // List<string> paths = ResourcesExtension.GetPathsRecursively(directory); // Gets list of files from Resources/directory

        string txtPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources", file_name + ".txt"); // writes the list of file paths to /Assets/Resources/
        if (File.Exists(txtPath))
        {
            File.Delete(txtPath);
        }
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(txtPath)) {}
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(txtPath, false))
        {
            foreach (string path in paths)
            {
                    writer.WriteLine(path);
            }
        }
        
    }
}

#endif
```

It uses the following [extension methods](https://gist.github.com/egemenertugrul/0a2a54c44896610ec7ce9954a3589226):

For files in StreamingAssets, use `StreamingAssetsExtension.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public static class StreamingAssetsExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively traverses each folder under <paramref name="path"/> and returns the list of file paths. 
    /// It will only work in Editor mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Relative to Application.streamingAssetsPath.</param>
    /// <param name="paths">List of file path strings.</param>
    /// <returns>List of file path strings.</returns>
    public static List<string> GetPathsRecursively(string path, ref List<string> paths)
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, path);
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (!file.Name.Contains(".meta"))
            {
                paths.Add(Path.Combine(path, file.Name)); // With file extension
            }
        }

        foreach (var dir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            GetPathsRecursively(Path.Combine(path, dir.Name), ref paths);
        }

        return paths;
    }

    public static List<string> GetPathsRecursively(string path)
    {
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();
        return GetPathsRecursively(path, ref paths);
    }
}
```

For files in Resources, use `ResourcesExtension.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public static class ResourcesExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively traverses each folder under <paramref name="path"/> and returns the list of file paths. 
    /// It will only work in Editor mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Relative to Application.streamingAssetsPath.</param>
    /// <param name="paths">List of file path strings.</param>
    /// <returns>List of file path strings.</returns>
    public static List<string> GetPathsRecursively(string path, ref List<string> paths)
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources", path);
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (!file.Name.Contains(".meta"))
            {
                paths.Add(Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name))); // Without file extension
            }
        }

        foreach (var dir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            GetPathsRecursively(Path.Combine(path, dir.Name), ref paths);
        }

        return paths;
    }

    public static List<string> GetPathsRecursively(string path)
    {
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();
        return GetPathsRecursively(path, ref paths);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively traverses each folder under <paramref name="basePath"/> and loads each file as a <typeparamref name="T"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="basePath"></param>
    /// <returns>Returns the loaded object of type <typeparamref name="T"/></returns>
    public static List<T> LoadRecursively<T>(string basePath) where T : Object
    {
        List<string> paths = GetPathsRecursively(basePath);

        List<T> objects = new List<T>();
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            objects.Add(Resources.Load<T>(path));
        }
        return objects;
    }

    public static List<(T, string)> LoadRecursivelyWithPaths<T>(string basePath) where T : Object
    {
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();
        GetPathsRecursively(basePath, ref paths);

        List<(T, string)> list = new List<(T, string)>();
        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            list.Add((Resources.Load<T>(path), path));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the file paths as the following:

```
// ...
List<string> filePathsList = new List<string>();
TextAsset paths = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(file_name); // i.e. StreamingAssetPaths.txt
string fs = paths.text;
string[] fLines = Regex.Split(fs, "\n|\r|\r\n");

foreach (string line in fLines)
{
    if (line.Length > 0)
        filePathsList.Add(line);
}
// ...

// Example of loading:
string examplePath = filePathsList[0];

// If the file is in StreamingAssets:
...
path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, examplePath);
byte[] data = null;
int dataLen = 0;
UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(path);
yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

if (webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
{
    dataLen = webRequest.downloadHandler.data.Length;
    data = webRequest.downloadHandler.data;
}
// do whatever you want with the data ...

// If the file is in Resources:
...
ObjectType obj = Resources.Load<ObjectType>(examplePath);
...
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this question is already been answered.... 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/210909/android-streamingassets-file-access.html

Comment: That answer is for accessing a file from the StreamingAssets folder which is not what I asked